# Python reading a file into unicode strings

Tags: python, string, file, unicode

I am having some troubles with understanding the correct way to handle unicode strings in Python. I have read many questions about it but it is still unclear what should I do to avoid problems when reading and writing files.

My goal is to read some huge (up to 7GB) files efficiently line by line. I was doing it with the simple `with open(filename) as f:` but it I ended up with an error in ASCII decoding.

Then I read the correct way of doing it would be to write:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as logfile:
```

However this ends up in:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 13: invalid start byte
```

Frankly I haven't understood why this exception is raised.

I have found a working solution doing:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in logfile:
        line = unicode(line, errors='ignore')
```

But this approach ended up being incredibly slow.
Therefore my question is:

Is there a correct way of doing this, and what is the fastest way?
Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% certain your file is UTF-8 encoded? Your error suggest your file is *at least* corrupted.

Comment: Don't use `codecs.open()`, by the way; use the newer and far more robust `io.open()` instead. You can specify an `errors` handler for that call.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I am not 100% sure it is utf-8 encoded. What seems strange is that I am able to open it regularly without considering utf-8. If it were to be corrupted shouldn't `open(filename)` raise an exception too?
If not, and therefore I am forced to go with the `unicode()` approach, is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: No, decoding only takes place as you read data, opening the file won't test all data in the file if it can be decoded up front.

Comment: In the end, you are processing 7GB of data as rich Unicode objects in Python. Expect some slowness *anyway*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data is probably *not* UTF-8 encoded. Figure out the correct encoding and use that instead. We can't tell you what codec is right, because we can't see your data.

If you must specify an error handler, you may as well do so when opening the file. Use the [`io.open()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open); `codecs` is an older library and has some issues that `io` (which underpins all I/O in Python 3 and was backported to Python 2) is far more robust and versatile.

The `io.open()` function takes an `errors` too:

```
import io

with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace') as logfile:
```

I picked `replace` as the error handler so you at least give you placeholder characters for anything that could not be decoded.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works and is slightly faster than the `unicode()` approach. Still it is way slower than the plain non unicode approach, but maybe there is no way of achieving comparable speeds.

Comment: @ClonedOne: depending on how you are processing those lines and what codec was really used, you could probably just treat the data as binary and not decode it.